# Call to a member function format() on string in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am passing the `fromdate` and `todate` from the view to controller. I want to print the betweens these dates from the database, but I get error like:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>   Call to a member function format() on string

**my view page**:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    {!! Form::open (['url' => 'admin/ad']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('', 'From date') !!}
        {!! Form::date('fromdate', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('', 'To date') !!}
        {!! Form::date('todate', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit(('submit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

**my controller page**:

```
$report = $request->report;
$fromdate = $request->fromdate; 
$start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($fromdate));
$todate = $request->todate;
$end_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($todate));

$users = Report::whereBetween('created_at', [
    $start_date->format('Y-m-d') . " 00:00:00",
    $end_date->format('Y-m-d') . " 23:59:59"
])->get();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$report = $request->report;
$fromdate = $request->fromdate; 
$start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($fromdate));
$todate = $request->todate;
$end_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($todate));
$users = Report::whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date,$end_date])->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) library to handle date parsing and formatting:

```
$users = Report::whereBetween('created_at', [
    Carbon::parse($request->fromdate)->toDateTimeString(), 
    Carbon::parse($request->todate)->toDateTimeString()
])->get();
```

See the **[Modifiers](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-modifiers)** section for `startOfXXXX` formatting:

```
$users = Report::whereBetween('created_at', [
    Carbon::parse($request->fromdate)->startOfDay(),  // 2012-01-31 00:00:00
    Carbon::parse($request->todate)->endOfDay()       // 2012-01-31 23:59:59
])->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

ok you me use

```
 {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($object->yourdate_fromdatabase)->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

place in your model:

```
protected $dates = ['fromdate', 'todate'];
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also make use of [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$report = $request->report;
$fromdate = $request->fromdate; 
$start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", strtotime($fromdate));
$todate = $request->todate;
$end_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", strtotime($todate));

$users = Report::whereBetween('created_at', [
    $start_date->format('Y-m-d') . " 00:00:00", 
    $end_date->format('Y-m-d') . " 23:59:59"
])->get();
```

Comment: If you happened to be someone who downvoted me for this answer, could you please explain why?